# Picture resize function when uploading in CodeIgniter not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, image-resizing

I made a function on the CodeIgniter framework so users can upload pictures of products to a product page. The thing is I want pictures to be resized to the width and height I want it to be. Since I added the image lib resize function in my upload function nothing is working anymore.

This is my upload function:

```
public function upload() {

    $this->load->library('upload');

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('product_form', $error);
    } else {
        $file_data = $this->upload->data();
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        foreach ($results as $row) {
            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config['source_image'] = './upload/' . $file_data["file_name"];
            $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $config['width'] = 75;
            $config['height'] = 50;

            $this->image_lib->clear();
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
        }

        $this->db->insert('products', array(
            'product_foto'         => $file_data['file_name'],
            'product_naam'         => $this->input->post('product_naam'),
            'product_beschrijving' => $this->input->post('product_beschrijving'),
            'product_categorie'    => $this->input->post('product_categorie'),
            'ophaal_plaats'        => $this->input->post('ophaal_plaats'),
            'date_created'         => date('Y-m-d'),
            'date_updated'         => date('Y-m-d')
        ));
        $data['img'] = base_url() . '/upload/' . $file_data['file_name'];
        header('location:https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/Product/');
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you missing the end/closing  } in your function?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: (Getting my Crayons out here...) :) Well you are missing a closing } in the code you have supplied in your question. I was just asking... is that a typo or its what you actually have in your code?

Comment: ah no thats not it I have an extra } in my code

Comment: In your foreach loop right?

Comment: $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE; Try with this

Comment: no not working.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me :

```
        if(!empty($_FILES['image_field']['name']))
        {

            $config['upload_path'] = './image_folder';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '262144';
            $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
            $this->load->library('upload',$config);
            if(!$this->upload->do_upload('image_field'))
            {
                echo "Not Upload";
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();
               // $this->session->set_flashdata('error','<div class="alert alert-warning">Something went wrong...try again...</div>');
                //redirect('Controller/function_name');
            }
            else
            {
                $image_data = $this->upload->data();
                $config1['image_library'] = 'gd2';

                $config1['source_image'] = './image_folder/'.$image_data['file_name'];
                $config1['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                $config1['quality'] = '50%';
                $config1['width'] = 50;
                $config1['height'] = 50;
                $this->load->library('image_lib', $config1);
                $this->image_lib->resize();
                if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
                {
                    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                }
                echo $image_data['file_name'];
                exit;
                // save to database    
            }
        }
```